# mocap_optitrack rigid body starting orientation

Tags: ros, mocap-optitrack, optitrack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to ensure the starting orientation of a rigid body is the same every time when configuring the rigid body for tracking?  Can the markers be configured so they match a world coordinated system?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63165/mocap_optitrack-rigid-body-starting-orientation/) by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2549 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nanaky](https://answers.ros.org/users/5617/nanaky/) on 2014-02-18**:
Hi,

I have the same question. Did you finally get the answer?

Thanks

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-12-16**:
If you care about a question please upvote it, don't add an answer so others don't think it's answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my experiences with my motion capture setup, there is no solution for this.  The trackable must be created coincident with frame of the motion capture system.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1